# B+ tree print elements is order

Tags: traversal, b-tree

I am trying to implement a B+ tree myself, but I want to create a method that prints what elements does the B+ tree have. If I use a traversal(in or post order) I will get also the elements in the parent nodes, therefore I will have duplicate values. Is there a way to solve this thing? 
Thanks

Comment: It would probably help if you post your code, or at least pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the nodes as you traverse them. Once the node is marked, it can't be traversed.