# Suggest an algorithm to traverse a B+ tree

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

Please suggest me an algorithm that will traverse a B+ tree of order 4 and display on the screen all its integer key entries in order of keys (smaller keys first). I have to write this in C++, but even pseudo code would be appreciated. Or even a small guide to write the algorithm will help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a good approach to use a [depth-first traversal in preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Traversals) and to [mark the visited nodes, to avoid traverse a visited node again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917715/b-tree-print-elements-is-order).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. How do I mark the visited objects? Is implementing a flag in the node class the proper way of doing this?

Comment: This is exactly the way to do this. Have a flag initialized to 0 in the node and change its value to 1 for every visited node.

Comment: if the B+ tree is sorted, then "mark the visited nodes" is a waste of memory. you only need to store the parent-node-path, all nodes left of the path have been visited

Answer (score 0):

its kind-of obvious when you look at a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) ...

[image: Bplus B+ Tree Data Structure]

assuming a **sorted** B+ tree, to visit all nodes in order:

- go to the leftmost leaf node (123), loop its values (abc)
- while the right-pointer is not null:

  - follow the right-pointer to the next leaf node (456), loop its values (def)

```py
def print_bplus_tree_leaf_nodes_inorder(root_node):
  """
  print leaf nodes of a B+ tree in-order
  """
  node = root_node
  while node.type == "branch":
    node = node.children[0] # go left to leftmost leaf node
  while node:
    assert node.type == "leaf"
    for idx, key in enumerate(node.keys): # loop keys of leaf node
      value = node.values[idx]
      print(f"{key}={value}", end=" ")
    node = node.right # go right to next leaf node
  print()

class BranchNode:
  def __init__(self, keys=[], children=[]):
    self.keys = keys
    self.children = children
    self.type = "branch"

class LeafNode:
  def __init__(self, keys=[], values=[]):
    self.keys = keys
    self.values = values
    self.right = None
    self.type = "leaf"

#     47_
# 123 456 789
# abc def ghi
root_node = BranchNode([4, 7, None], [
  LeafNode([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]),
  LeafNode([4, 5, 6], ["d", "e", "f"]),
  LeafNode([7, 8, 9], ["g", "h", "i"]),
])

# set right pointers of leaf nodes
root_node.children[0].right = root_node.children[1]
root_node.children[1].right = root_node.children[2]
root_node.children[2].right = None

print_bplus_tree_leaf_nodes_inorder(root_node)

# result:
# 1=a 2=b 3=c 4=d 5=e 6=f 7=g 8=h 9=i
```

---

if your B+ tree is **not sorted**, then you can create a buffer of values, and sort that buffer

---

if your B+ tree does **not** have right-pointers, then have a look at iterative binary tree walkers. to iterate the **leaf** nodes of a **binary** tree:

```py
def print_binary_tree_leaf_nodes_inorder(root_node):
  """
  print leaf nodes of a binary tree in-order
  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/
  """
  def is_leaf(node):
    return node.left == None and node.right == None
  node = root_node
  stack = []
  while True:
    if node:
      stack.append(node)
      node = node.left # go left
    elif stack:
      node = stack.pop() # go up
      if is_leaf(node):
        print(node.value, end=" ")
      node = node.right # go right
    else:
      break
  print()

class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

#    4
#  2   6
# 1 3 5 7
root_node = Node(
  value=4,
  left=Node(
    value=2,
    left=Node(1),
    right=Node(3),
  ),
  right=Node(
    value=6,
    left=Node(5),
    right=Node(7),
  ),
)

print_binary_tree_leaf_nodes_inorder(root_node)

# result:
# 1 3 5 7
```

in a B+ tree, any node can have more than 2 child nodes. so where a binary tree walker would "go right", a B+ tree walker must loop over an array of child nodes